# what math technique should I use to model a music wave?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to model a violin note recording (Concert A - 440Hz), picture as below (second graph)
[Violin note recording output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebUTx.jpg)

any suggestion or resource is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Google search on "violin sound fourier series" or "fourier series musical instruments" may help.

Comment: There are 3 components in music: attacks/percussives, steady periodic waves, and noise/random signal. Violin mixes the 3.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approximate a sound wave is as a sine wave, i.e.:

$$y(t) = A \sin(2\pi Ft + \phi)$$

Where $A$ is the amplitude of the wave, $F$ is the frequency, and $\phi$ is a phase angle based on where in the wave you are when starting the recording.

However, real-world musical instruments tend not to produce just one pure frequency, but have [overtones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone).  These are *usually* modeled as integer multiples of the fundamental frequency, aka “harmonics”.  (Drums, however, have non-harmonic overtones, [with much more complicated math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane).)  This gives us the slightly more complicated model:

$$y(t) = \sum_{k=1}^N A_k \sin(2\pi kFt + \phi_k)$$

Where $N$ is the maximum number of overtones you can expect to be audible, and $k$ is an integer multiplier for the frequency.  Such a sum of sinusoids is called a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

Now you “just” need to apply a curve-fitting algorithm to match the $A_k$ and $\phi_k$ values to your recorded sound wave.